# Сдвинуть текст по кнопке

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно по кнопке сдвигать текст и чтобы левая часть скрывалась.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD**
Вот вариант с возможностью удалять и добавлять спаны с цифрами:

```js
let hideShow = function() {
  let i = $('span').length;
  $('.hide').click(function(){ 
    if(i == 0) return;
    $('span:last-of-type').remove();
    i--;
  });
  $('.show').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('.wrapper>div').append('<span>'+i+'</span> ');
  })
}
hideShow();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <button class="hide">Скрыть</button>
  <button class="show">Показать</button>
</div>
```

---

Так?

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('span:first-of-type').remove();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно. Я немного изменил код, добавив дополнительную кнопку "show". 
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('span:first-of-type').hide();
});
$('.show').click(function() {
  $('span:first-of-type').show();
})

Но срабатывает только 1 раз, как можно это исправить?

Comment: @Alex, ну, естественно, Вы же не удаляете элемент (как я делаю в своём скрипте), а только скрываете его. Соответственно селектор span:first-of-type будет срабатывать только для первого элемента. Тут уже скрипт посложнее нужен

Comment: @Alex, я добавил вариант, который, очевидно, больше Вам подходит

Comment: Спасибо большое